# How to call a function in a Switch Statement using powershell script

Tags: function, switch-statement, powershell-5.0

The PowerShell version I am using is 5.0. I have a situation where I need to use a function and call it within a `switch` statement. My work involves to do couple of operations.

In brief, my scenario is the inputs for the `switch` statement are two A and B. I have to call a function declared in switch "condition A" in switch "conditionB", I mean execute the same set of operation.

**Exception:**

```
installsw is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
 CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (regupgrade:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```bsh
$condi = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the input"
switch ($condi) {
    A {
        function installsw() {
            Write-Host "install necessary sw" 
            install some s/w using "Start-Process" Command 
        }
        installsw
    }
    B {
        Write-Host "s/w upgrade"
        installsw
        $logs = Copy-Item -Path"D:/var" -Destination "D:/Temp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define installsw before the switch.  Unless $condi is 'A', the installsw function won't be defined.

Btw, you can run any pipeline inside the first switch line:

```
 switch (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the input") {
```

Comment: Hi @js2010 , you say to declare it as global function , so it can be called anytime.

Comment: Yes, or at least inside the same script.  Unless $condi is 'A', it won't be defined.

Comment: Hi @js2010 Is it possible to create the function in switch condition A and use it again for condition B ?

Comment: You can define it in both conditions if you really want to.